# How to copy every nth row to entire dataset

Tags: r

[image]I want to replace values in 1 row to value in 1:6 row, value in 7 row to 7:12, value in 13 row to 13:18 and so on. I can do it in excel. But i want to do it in r. Is it possible. I can do it by one by one. But it will take too much time.

```
like so
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example of input and expected output?

Comment: Maybe: `x <- x[rep(seq(1, nrow(x), 6), each=6),]` ?

Comment: @ Gki Thanks you save my day